# dnsmasq no address available?

Tags: rhel, dnsmasq

I am getting this error in my `/var/log/messages` file.

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[xxxx] DHCPDISCOVER(xxxxxx) xx:xx:xx:xx no address available
```

How can I tell what leases dnsmasq has leased out? And how can I free them up?

I'm running RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand your range by editing the config file:

```
vi /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

Look for the `dhcp-range` line:

```
dhcp-range=192.168.0.10,192.168.0.50,12h
```

will issue from `192.168.0.10` to `192.168.0.50` with a lease time of 12 hours.

You can see your current leases with:

```
cat /var/lib/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.leases
```

That path might differ, depending on your distro.  If it's not there, check the config file above for:

```
dhcp-leasefile=<path to lease file>
```

Here's a minimal example config:

```
interface=eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.0.10,192.168.0.50,12h
dhcp-options=3,192.168.0.1
```

which listens on `eth0` and issues `192.168.0.10` to `192.168.0.50` with a lease time of 12 hours. It also sends the default gateway  (the `3`) as `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: all the lines in my /etc/dnsmasq.conf are commented out and I have no /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases file.

Comment: Hmm!  Add your distro to your question - it may help us track it down.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

Comment: You need to configure `dnsmasq` before it works.  I've just installed it on a RHEL6.5 VM and all of `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` is commented out; just as you found yours.